# Improvement in for loop using other method

Tags: r, optimization, data.table, dplyr

**Problem**

There is 1 main station (`df`) and 3 local stations (`s`) stacked in a single data.frame with values for three days.  The idea is to take each day from the main station, find the relative anomaly of the three local stations, and smooth it using inverse distance weighting (IDW) from the `phylin` package.  This is then applied to the `value` in the main station by multiplication.

Any suggestions on improving this code (e.g. `data.table`, `dplyr`, `apply`)?  I still don't know how to approach this problem without the cumbersome `for` loop.

**dput**

```
s <- structure(list(id = c("USC00031152", "USC00034638", "USC00036352", 
"USC00031152", "USC00034638", "USC00036352", "USC00031152", "USC00034638", 
"USC00036352"), lat = c(33.59, 34.7392, 35.2833, 33.59, 34.7392, 
35.2833, 33.59, 34.7392, 35.2833), long = c(-92.8236, -90.7664, 
-93.1, -92.8236, -90.7664, -93.1, -92.8236, -90.7664, -93.1), 
    year = c(1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 
    1900), month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), day = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), value = c(63.3157576809045, 
    86.0490598902219, 76.506386949066, 71.3760752788486, 89.9119576975542, 
    76.3535163951321, 53.7259645981243, 61.7989638892985, 85.8911224149051
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), .Names = c("id", "lat", "long", "year", "month", "day", 
"value"))

df <- structure(list(id = c(12345, 12345, 12345), lat = c(100, 100, 
100), long = c(50, 50, 50), year = c(1900, 1900, 1900), month = c(1, 
1, 1), day = 1:3, value = c(54.8780020601509, 106.966029162171, 
98.3198828955801)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", 
"lat", "long", "year", "month", "day", "value"))
```

**Code**

```
library(phylin)

nearest <- function(i, loc){
  # Stack 3 local stations
  stack <- s[loc:(loc+2),]

  # Get 1 main station
  station <- df[i,]

  # Check for NA and build relative anomaly (r)
  stack <- stack[!is.na(stack$value),]
  stack$r <- stack$value/station$value

  # Use IDW and return v
  v <- as.numeric(ifelse(dim(stack)[1] == 1, 
                    stack$r, 
                    idw(stack$r, stack[,c(2,3,8)], station[,2:3])))
  return(v)
}  


ncdc <- 1

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  # Get relative anomaly from function
  r <- nearest(i, ncdc)

  # Get value from main station and apply anomaly
  p <- df[i,7]              
  df[i,7] <- p*r   

  # Iterate to next 3 local stations 
  ncdc <- ncdc + 3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you let your nearest function unchanged. 
Then you could get your new value column in df by

```
newvalue <- sapply(1:NROW(df), function (i) df[i,7] * nearest(i, 3*(i-1)+1))
df$value <- newvalue
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is a good use of the `apply` function and I wonder if it could be paralleled to improve the speed.

Comment: For a parallel version of apply you should take a look at `mcapply` in the `multicore` package.